# How to solve a type mismatch in vba when there seems to be no mismatch?

Tags: vba

```
Public Sub ComboBoxPopulate()
    Sheets("MSS").Select
    
    
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim cmbox_opt As String
    Dim array_cmbox As ArrayList
    Set array_cmbox = New ArrayList
    Dim last_row As Integer
    
    last_row = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For counter = 3 To last_row
        cmbox_opt = Range("B" & counter).Value
        If IsInArray(cmbox_opt, array_cmbox) Then
            array_cmbox.Add cmbox_opt = False
        Else
            array_cmbox.Add cmbox_opt
        End If
    Next
        
End Sub
 

Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False

End Function
```

Hi I'm trying to figure out why it's telling me that I have a type mismatch when I try to use the IsInArray function to determine if cmbox_opt is in the empty array. I used the VarType function to ensure that cmbox_opt is indeed a string and it is. So I don't understand why it wont accept it as a parameter inside the IsInArray function?

Comment: Side note. Using `Application.Match()` to determine if an element exists in an array is more efficient than a loop: `IsInArray = IsNumeric(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are treating an ArrayList as an array.

ArrayList does have a `comtains` method, so I don't think you need or want `IsInArray` anyway.

I'm not sure what you intend by

```
array_cmbox.Add cmbox_opt = False
```

but if that isn't your problem then I'd imagine it's equivalent to

```
array_cmbox.Add False
```

in which case you're asking a boolean to a string ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks a lot you were right I just needed to use the contains method

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming from LBound(arr) and UBound(arr).  The parameter in both these functions is an Array not an ArrayList, hence the Type Mismatch.  The error has nothing to do with the type of cmb_opt.

You were led to believe that the problem was different, because the error gets thrown as you step over your function call.  However, in such a case, you should put a breakpoint within the function.  That would have revealed on which line within the function the error was thrown, which would have made it more obvious to you.

As JSmart523 has pointed out Contains is much easier for your purpose.  Use this instead:

```
Dim counter As Integer
Dim cmbox_opt As String
Dim array_cmbox As ArrayList
Set array_cmbox = New ArrayList
Dim last_row As Integer

last_row = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For counter = 3 To last_row
    cmbox_opt = Range("B" & counter).Value
    If Not array_cmbox.Contains(cmbox_opt) Then
        array_cmbox.Add cmbox_opt
    End If
Next
```